# Seeking references on solving a system of differential inequalities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Abstracting from the boundary value conditions for a moment, would somebody please direct me to some references on solving differential inequalities of the following form?

Find $u(x)$ that satisfies:

(i) $F(x,u,u'') = 0$

(ii) $a_0 \le G(x,u,u'',u''') \le a_1$, for some constants $a_0, a_1$

(iii) $b_0 \le H(x,u,u'',u''') \le b_1$, for some constants $b_0, b_1$.

Any references that provide conditions for establishing the existence (or even uniqueness) of $u$ would be greatly appreciated! If there are any further references on numerical procedures to solve the problem is even better!

PS. I would have Googled up this problem myself but the keywords "differential inequalities" are not really referring to the type of problem I have in mind.